# Prove that the antipodal mapping is an isometry on $S^n$. Help understanding the proof.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, spheres

Prove that the antipodal mapping $A: S^n \to S^n$ given by $A(p)=-p$ is an isometry.

I know that in order to prove that a map $f$ is an isometry of a smooth manifold $M$ it must hold true that
$$\langle v,u\rangle_p = \langle d_f v, d_fu \rangle_{f(p)}$$

Now I found online [this document](http://image.sciencenet.cn/olddata/kexue.com.cn/upload/blog/file/2009/9/2009941352126256.pdf) that proves this exercise (Exercise 1.1.). I cannot follow it though. It basically says that in order to prove this we first need to claim that $T_{p}S^n = T_{A(p)}S^n$ and for this it is enough to prove that $T_{p}S^n \subset T_{A(p)}S^n$. **Why is this true?** In order to show this they claim that $T_{A(p)}S^n \subset \subset T_{A \circ A(p)}S^n = T_pS^n$. **What does the $\subset \subset$ mean** and **why the last relation holds true, i.e. why $T_{A(p)S^n}=T_pS^n$ since these tangent spaces are defined in different points?**

Finally, **why they later claim that $dA_pv = -v$?** I do not understand why this also holds true.

Comment: I suspect that in this particular case you can show it's an isometry without knowing about isometries of smooth manifolds in general.

Comment: I don't follow the proof in the document either, but you should be able to easily prove a more general fact: if $A$ is a smooth isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is also an isometry of any Riemmanian manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced metric.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Note that whenever the term "isometry" appears in the context of Riemannian manifolds, it means something slightly different than what it means in the case of metric spaces.

Comment: If this were not true we would have abolished differential geometry long ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the remaining question, the proof of the equation of tangent planes $T_p S^2 = T_{A(p)}S^2$ is obtained by tracing through the definitions and doing some multivariable calculus computations.

First, $S^2$ is the solution set of the equation 
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2-1=0
$$
Second, the gradient of the left hand side of this equation at the point $p=(a,b,c)$ is computed to be
$$\nabla_p(f) = \langle 2a,2b,2c\rangle
$$ 
and the tangent plane $T_p S^2$ is the perpendicular plane to $\nabla_p(f)$ which is computed to be the set vectors 
$$T_p S^2 = \{\langle x,y,z \rangle \bigm| ax+by+cz=0 \}
$$
Third, the gradient at the point $A(p)=(-a,-b,-c)$ is computed to be
$$\nabla_{A(p)}(f)=\langle-2a,-2b,-2c\rangle
$$
and $T_{A(p)}S^2$ is the perpendicular plane to $\nabla_{A(p)}(f)$ which is computed to be the exact same set of vectors 
$$T_{A(p)}S^2 = \{\langle x,y,z \rangle \bigm| ax+by+cz=0 \}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. I am quite new to the subject and I do not understand the notation $\langle a,b,c \rangle$. E.g. from do Carmo's book that I read, $\langle a,b \rangle$ would be something like the matrix of the metric: $g_{ab}$. So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Marion: This is simply the notation for vectors in a Cartesian coordinate system: $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is a vector with three components $a$, $b$, and $c$. I'll say that my answer contains nothing about differential geometry, only basic notations and results about multivariable calculus as one would find in an introductory text on differential topology, or even an ordinary calculus book.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I am used to $(a,b,c)$ in physics so this would explain my confusion.

Answer (score 6):

As user 7530 suggests, the antipodal map on the sphere is the restriction to the sphere of the $-id$ map on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Note that $-id$ is linear, and hence, its derivative at a point is also equal to $-id$. More explicitly, for a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, identify the tangent space $T_p\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then for any $v\in T_p\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we have$$d(-id)_p(v)=-v\in T_{-p}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$$Consequently, for any $u,v\in T_p\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we have$$\langle d(-id)_p(u),d(-id)_p(v)\rangle=\langle-u,-v\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle,$$and so $-id$ is an isometry.

**Edit:** We show $T_pS^n=T_{-p}S^n$. The argument is essentially the one used in Lee's answer, but spelled out differently. Let $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S^n$ satisfy $\alpha(0)=p$. We have$$\langle\alpha(t),\alpha(t)\rangle=const,$$and differentiating at $t=0$, using the Leibniz rule, we obtain$$\langle\dot{\alpha}(0),p\rangle=0.$$Hence,$$T_pS^n\subset p^\bot.$$It now follows from dimension consideration that in fact$$T_pS^n=p^\bot.$$Since $p^\bot=(-p)^\bot$, we are done.

**Remarak:** As commented bellow, the fact that $T_pS^n=T_{-p}S^n$ may be interesting in general, but is not crucial for this question. Every $M\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ restricts to an isometry of $S^n$, and the antipodal map is just a particular case.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I cannot connect it with my question very well. The way you prove it is the same as the way I want to but I prefer to use the antipodal map and $TS^n$ instead of an immersion or embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: @Marion Of course, we like to think of $S^n$ as a manifold on its own, rather than a submanifold of Euclidean space, whenever possible.  However, you're asking about the antipodal map. Note that this map is only defined in means of the Euclidean space. Furthermore, you think of the sphere as a Riemannian manifold, even though you didn't specify any Riemannian metric. This is because (maybe without noticing) you equip the sphere with the metric induced by the standard embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @AmiatiYuval thanks a lot for your very helpful comments. I would still like to know why $T_{A(p)}S^n = T_{p}S^{n}$ for example and why $\langle v,u \rangle_p = \langle v,u \rangle_{-p}$. Thanks.

Comment: It's true that $T_{A(p)}S^n = T_pS^n$ but focusing on this fact is a red herring: Amitai did not use it in his proof. (If you want to prove it, you can do so by finding a basis for the tangent space at $p$ and $-p$ and checking that they span the same $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane.)

Comment: What *is* essential is that (1) the pushforward $A_*$ maps vectors in $T_pS^n$ to vectors in $T_{A(p)}S^n$ (this is true for *any* differentiable map, not just isometries) and (2) that for the antipodal map, this pushforward is just $-I$ in the ambient Euclidean coordinates.

Comment: @Marion Please see the edit.